# How can I find all possible values for an option in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have an option, for example `AxesStyle`, how can I find possible values for it? I know that one of the possible values is `Arrowheads`, but can I find others? I was looking for lists or something like that but have been unsuccessful so far.

Is there some command like `Options[]`, or `?TicksStyle`? I know that these commands are not for this, but just to get a point.

Comment: As indicated in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Axes.html), for the various `Graphics` functions, `Axes` is either a Boolean or an array of Booleans that indicate which axes are to be included in the given `Graphics` object.

Comment: Currently, it is not possible to find all possible values for a given option. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8625296/616736) and Sjoerd's comments under Prashant's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, the possible values for an option are incompletely documented. For example, try to find out what the legal values are for the option `Method` when used in `Plot`. The ref page for `Plot` merely gives the default value for `Method` and describes it in very general terms. In the Examples section of that page, `Method` is not even included among the options with examples. And the ref page for `Method` seems to give no help on this, either. On the latter page there is a link to the guide page [Graphics Options And Styling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsOptionsAndStyling.html), and on that guide page the item 'Method' appears under category "Tweaking Rendering" -- but again no help on what values might be available!

Answer (score 3):

If you check the help file for the various things you're asking about and click the "More Information" dropdown it will give you all the options.

**Edit**: To clarify, be sure to check the help file for the specific setting you're looking for, not the function which is using it.

Comment: thank you, I've seen that. And it gives me all the possible options, and one value for each, but what about others. For example for Plot->FillingStyle-> it's given there Automatic, but how to find out what are the other possible choices?

Comment: @balboa - For your example, you could look under Plot - Options - FillingStyle for more information, or look up FillingStyle directly for other examples. That's not comprehensive though. Try here for more examples.

Comment: You looked at the options for `Plot`. That shows the default value for `FillingStyle` as used in `Plot`. If you check the help page for `FillingStyle` it will give much more information. For example, the first info piece on that help page says "FillingStyle->g specifies that all filling should be done by default with the specified graphics directive."

Comment: Ok, I see it is a bit complicated, and as I understood there is no easy way that mathematica lists options's possible values. I should get familiar with directives.

Answer (score 2):

The main places to look for documentation for an option are the documentation pages for the option, and for the function that takes the option.  Open up the various sections, starting with *More Information*, but also including sections like *Scope* (which frequently has sub-categories.)

When looking at documentation for functions, there is an entire section titled *Options* that has individual options as a sub-section.  So you could look at *ListPlot > Examples > Options > Filling* which contains quite a lot.

When looking at documentation for options, especially for graphics functions, the examples may just show how you can use the option with a representative function, such as `Plot`.  Usually similar functions like `ListPlot`, `LogPlot`, etc... will accept similar settings for the option.

Comment: Thank you for answer, these examples in sub-sections are useful.

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated in the questions you can use Options to see what is available.

So,

```
Options[Plot]
```

Returns,

```
{AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True,
AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> {}, 
Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorOutput -> Automatic, 
ContentSelectable -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction, Epilog -> {}, 
Evaluated -> Automatic, EvaluationMonitor -> None, 
Exclusions -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> None, Filling -> None, 
FillingStyle -> Automatic, FormatType :> TraditionalForm, 
Frame -> False, FrameLabel -> None, FrameStyle -> {}, 
FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameTicksStyle -> {}, GridLines -> None, 
GridLinesStyle -> {}, ImageMargins -> 0., ImagePadding -> All, 
ImageSize -> Automatic, ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, 
MaxRecursion -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
MeshShading -> None, MeshStyle -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, 
PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotLabel -> None, 
PlotLegends -> None, PlotPoints -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> {Full, Automatic}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
PlotStyle -> Automatic, PlotTheme :> $PlotTheme, 
PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, 
RegionFunction -> (True &), RotateLabel -> True, 
TargetUnits -> Automatic, Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}, 
WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}
```